# Finding Car plate white pixel with Matlab

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

I would like to recognize one white pixel of the carplate on a image. I do not know how to recignize it because the color of the car is somewhere more "whiter" than the carplate's white color. I wrote a runable code but I have to select one of the car plate points with mouse, and then I found the carplate and I could draw a rectangle around it. 
Do you have any idea how to automatize finding one white pixel of the carplate?

Here is the code:

```
clear all;
close all;

I= imread('volvo_frame_0001.bmp');

figure, imshow(I)

level=0.5;

BW=im2bw(I,level);
figure, imshow(BW);

BW2 = bwselect(BW,4);
figure, imshow(BW2);
hold on;

C = corner(BW2);

min_x = min(C(:,1));

max_x = max(C(:,1));

min_y = min(C(:,2));

max_y = max(C(:,2));


figure, imshow(I);
hold on;

BoxPolygon = [min_x, max_y; max_x, max_y; max_x, min_y; min_x, min_y; min_x, max_y;];
line(BoxPolygon(:, 1), BoxPolygon(:, 2), 'Color', 'g');
```

Comment: LPR is extremely difficult and can not be solved by simply identifying a white pixel on the license plate. To get LPR to work by using a moderately easy approach you have to have hard restrictions on your input images. What is the setting for your car images, is there only one car in the image? Is the car photographed straight from behind? Will the license plate always be located in some part of the image? Are the images high resolution? What are the lighting conditions? It is not possible to give you guidance without knowing what kind of input you are working with.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the answer of your question is an application field called Licence Plate Recognition ([LPR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_number_plate_recognition)) in which you can find hundreds, if we don't say thousands, of programs either in Matlab or any other language, such as a [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41391-licence-plate-recognition) free Matlab code.

Anyway, if you insist on writing the code from the scratch, I suggest you not to look for white pixels! because you can't tell a pixel is white or not since the pixels values are in wide range (0 - 256^3) and the "color label" is a term which you cannot simply assign to a pixel (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aOptical_grey_squares_orange_brown.svg) as an illustration to the fact). Instead you better use other "features" of plates. Such as the fact that a plate is a "rectangle" and is the one with identical "ratio" of sides. Thereafter you can use "[canny](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector)" to find edges (dramatic changes of light or color in an image) by which shape characteristics can be more easily judged. which means you can more easily find rectangles within this kind of image.

When you found rectangles, you can check some other "features" within those rectangles to ensure whether the rectangle is a plate or some other form of object which is close to a plate in shape, not in content. For example the histogram or any other method.

Hope this helps

Cheers